# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header for React.js app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, cors, preflight

I'm trying to delete a user from a simple React.js app. I'm receiving a 302 error and my console displays this error as well.

> Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:3001/. Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque
>   response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to
>   fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>
> Uncaught (in promise)TypeError: Failed to fetch

My delete request on client side looks like this:

```
export function deleteUser(id){
  return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/${id}`, {
    method: 'DELETE'
  }).then( res => res.json() )
}
```

And the function in the top level container is this:

```
handleDeleteUser(id){
    localStorage.clear('token')
    deleteUser(id)
    .then((data) => this.setState({
      current_user: data
    }))
  }
```

I've come across a lot of answers regarding CORS. This is my application.rb file from the server side:

```
module Our_gardenApi
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.api_only = true

     config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :patch, :options]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My UsersController is also attempting to redirect like so:

```
def destroy
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.destroy
  redirect_to "http://localhost:3001"
end
```

The gem 'rack-cors' is also installed within my Gemfile.

In the end, the user is successfully deleted. I'm just running into issues with the redirection. 
**Any help with explanation would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: try reading CORS documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: have you added `rack-cors` gem into your gem file

Comment: Hey @AshishJambhulkar. Yes I did. Forgot to mention that. Thanks!

Comment: The error message shows `Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:3001/` while your snippet with your frontend code shows it’s making the request `http://localhost:3000`. That is, different ports—3001 vs 3000. If that mismatch is just a typo, you probably want to update the question to correct it. But I notice you say you’re seeing a 302 (redirect). Is that because your request to `http://localhost:3000` is getting redirected to `http://localhost:3001/`? And maybe you’ve configured CORS support on the  `http://localhost:3000` server backend but not the `http://localhost:3001/` server backend?

Comment: @sideshowbarker Hey! Thanks for the feedback. My CORS knowledge is pretty weak, but I'm under the assumption that I am allowing requests to be sent/received from different ports with the `origins'*'` line in my application.rb file (server side).

The reason for different ports 3000 vs 3001 is because the rails backend server is running on 3000, so that is where my database is stored. The client side is being displayed at 3001. I'm making fetch requests and using that backend 3000 url, which hits a certain controller#action within the appropriate rails backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this gem into your gem file:

https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors

run bundle install

and then make this configuration in your application.rb file

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # ...

    # Rails 5

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end

    # Rails 3/4

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ashishJambulkar. Removing the :delete and :patch methods causes an error when editing other content throughout the site. Appreciate the efforts though!!